# handling Javascript function

Tags: javascript

I have a JavaScript function which is used to copy data in my HTML page.
After clicking a button in the same HTML, a function is getting called. Till this everything is fine. But when I again click on same button, the same thing was getting copied twice. This should not happen. I want to copy content only one time.

```
<script language="JavaScript">
   var x=1;
   function h1b_cnslr() {
       if (x===1){
          x=2
          some code  
       }
   } 
   function h1b_nocnslr() {
       if (x===1){
          x=2
          some code  }
       }        
   } 
</script> 
<BUTTON id ="btn_h1b_cnslr" class="copy" onClick="h1b_cnslr();" value="Copy" >Copy</BUTTON>  
<BUTTON id ="btn_h1b_nocnslr" class="copy" onClick="h1b_nocnslr();" value="Copy" >Copy</BUTTON>
```

I am using variable `x`. The logic I used is, globally `x=1` and when the user clicks for the first time `x` will get assigned `2`. For the second click the value of `x` will be checked and if `x===1`, only then will it enter into the loop. But everytime `x` is assigned as `1` as I declared `x` as a global variable. Is their any other way to do this?

Comment: Almost sounds like your buttons causes postbacks and this will obviously reset x back to 1 every time? If I am getting what you're trying to say here?

Comment: Rather using this flag var why not check innerhtml is empty before  copying the content. (if only one time copy is requirement.)

Answer (score 0):

Put another var to check if you already have copied the content else skip copy